# Why does my DPAPI data start with the same bits?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, windows-dpapi

I am using the DPAPI C# ProtectedData class to encrypt some information stored in the database.  I am using it both with and without the `optionalEntropy`.  Encrypting the same data multiple times, the first 80 characters (~60 bytes, I believe, base-64) are always the same.  Shouldn't they be different?

```
-- With IV
--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
--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
--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

--Without IV
--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
--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
--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
```

CCY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DPAPI blobs contain more than just the raw encrypted data. They also have some metadata, like the structure version, the GUID of the cryptographic provider, the GUID of [the DPAPI key](http://www.passcape.com/windows_password_recovery_dpapi_master_key), and so on. You can read more on the various fields [on this Passcape page](http://www.passcape.com/windows_password_recovery_dpapi_analyse).

Using [this Base64 decoder](https://conv.darkbyte.ru/), I see something that looks like a DWORD representing the value 1 (`01 00 00 00`). That's followed by the standard GUID for the Windows DPAPI provider. After four more bytes that look like another DWORD, I see something as wide as a GUID: 16 bytes. That's probably the DPAPI key's GUID.

That all adds up to 40 bytes, and along with the other cryptographic parameters (e.g. the algorithm used), you get your constant roughly-60 bytes. The actual encrypted data is indeed very different in each case.

Answer (score 0):

The device seems to use the `ProtectedData.Protect()` method which is available in .NET

Using something like this in C#

```
    byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MySecretString");
    byte[] encryptedPasswordBytes = ProtectedData.Protect(passwordBytes, null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
    encryptedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedPasswordBytes);
```

You will get for `encrptedPassword`:

```
AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAA0Ro/rmV19kWDHMSntiPwBQAAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAACSndrddMZt6dVWujI9gMcDAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAALnqq651QnnR4xNsMYii7XYQAAAAY1gX++xauABuecqREe75KRQAAAAnWOtfKPSj7ngsQOcqqqGCO8o+Kg==
```

The first 32 bytes `AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAA` seem to be the fixed header.